# Hadoop Cluster Configuration

Tags: hadoop

Now I would like to add a new Datanode to my hadoop cluster
Do I need to stop or switch off the hadoop cluster and add a new datanode 
How do I add a new datanode in to hadoop cluster

Answer (score 1):

Basically you stop your cluster, add the node's IP address to the `conf/slaves`, and re-start the cluster again.

PS: Iff starting and stopping is annoying (and can take up to hours in large clusters with massive amount of files) you can add some artificial IPs in there and when more slaves are joining the cluster you simply start them up. Hadoop does not care how many slaves there are configured or down: it will use what it can get. And defining not-yet-existing slaves is good practice to hot-join slaves in Hadoop.

Comment: So Is it Mandatory to Stop my cluster before I add new Data node?

Comment: In this case: yes. Because every other TT and DN have to know about your entire cluster (and the slaves configuration is populated on startup only).

Comment: And because this is kind of odd you can add 'reserved' (not yet joined) IPs for future nodes. This way you only need to take down your cluster when your reserved IPs ran out :-) This was bothering me as well. And some companies like facebook will not restart a Hadoop cluster for adding nodes. I think this is the way massive clusters are configured.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to shutdown or restart the entire cluster in this case.
First, add the new node's hostname to the conf/slaves file on the master node. 
Also add the ipaddress and hostname in the etc/hosts file on all machines in order for them to communicate. Then log in to the new slave node and execute the following commands:

```
$ cd path/to/hadoop 
$ bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode 
$ bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restart your hadoop cluster. As per this [document](http://webthanga.blogspot.in/2016/01/add-new-datanode-in-existing-hadoop.html), You can add nodes in the includes file and and making some changes in the hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml files, you can achieve this. Detailed instructions are given in the [this document](http://webthanga.blogspot.in/2016/01/add-new-datanode-in-existing-hadoop.html)